# Starting td-agent for fluentd

Tags: logging, fluentd, td-agent

How to start td-agent service for fluentd configuration file which is not in the default /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf location? 
I tried with

```
td-agent -c /home/charith/Documents/fdConfig/configuration.conf
```

but not sure how to restart the service after a change in a log file happens!

Answer (score 2):

The default location of configuration file is `etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf`.
By using `sudo systemctl restart td-agent` will restart the file at the default location. If started by `td-agent -c configuration.conf` only way to restart is first press ctrl+c to stop and then again restart using the same command.